# Get coordinates of desired area to be used as parameters for roipoly

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to set the zebra lane as my ROI. The function 'roipoly' lets me define a region of interest and returns a binary mask (which is what I need for the next step: vision.blobAnalysis).

Visually, this I what I want to achieve:
[image] 
(yes with a visible rectangle covering the ROI.)

Roipoly has variations that differs in their parameters:

BW = roipoly(I, c, r) and BW = roipoly(x, y, I, xi, yi). If I'm not mistaken the c,r and x,y,xi,yi are coordinates.

Which one of these should I use and how do I supply the coordinate parameters? Also, if you know other options to accomplish the same goal, please enlighten me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [getrect](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/getrect.html) for selecting the rectangle with mouse, then convert selected coordinates to [roipoly](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/roipoly.html) input format.

I used the function [insertShape](https://www.google.co.il/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=insertshape%20matlab&*), to draw a red rectangle.
(You can use other methods if you have no access to the requited toolbox).

I were using `BW = roipoly(I, c, r)` version, which takes image size form image `I`.

Here is my code:

```
%Read input image.
I = imread('autumn.tif');
h = figure;
imshow(I);

%Specify rectangle with mouse
rect = getrect(h);

%Draw red rectangle (replace pixels data with red color).
J = insertShape(I, 'Rectangle', rect, 'Color', [220, 0, 0], 'LineWidth', 3);
imshow(J);

%Compute rows and columns parameters from selected rect, to expected format of roipoly:
% (x0,y0) is top left corner, and (x1,y1) is bottom right corner.
x0 = rect(1);
y0 = rect(2);
x1 = x0 + rect(3) - 1; %rect(3) is width of rectangle.
y1 = y0 + rect(4) - 1; %rect(4) is height of rectangle.

%Imagine drawing lines from (x0,y0) to (x1,y0) to (x1,y1) to (x0,y1), [and back to (x0,y0), which closes the polygon] 
c = [x0, x1, x1, x0];
r = [y0, y0, y1, y1];

BW = roipoly(I, c, r);
figure;imshow(BW);
```

Result (after selecting a rectangle):
[image]

[image]